# Android Singleton Method

Tags: android, singleton

So I'm trying to make an application using the Singleton Method. I want to have a class that stores all the information about my device's bluetooth state/connections/devices, and I want to make multiple activites that can access these methods.

I know that I need to have a class that extends Application, then I can access everything by calling getApplication(). What I do not understand, is where I initialize this object. From my frame of reference, I have all of these separate Activities, and if I initialize the object in one, I'm going to need to use intents to pass the object to the next activity, which completely defeats the purpose of using the singleton method.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extended Application your class will be created as your app launches. It can be retrieved in Activity classes using getApplication()

Comment: Thank you! So it is automatically initialized? So if I make a constructor for the class, it is executed before the class starts, and basically any time I want to access it in any Activity i just call "getApplication().anyMethod()?"

Comment: It has an onCreate method which will be called automatically where you can do your initialisation. Yes, you can access it with getApplication()

Answer (score 2):

Simply extend from `android.app.Application`. Then register it as the application class in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application android:name="mypackage.MyApplication" ...>
```

In your class you will receive usual Android calls, such as in

```
@Override
public void onCreate() { }
```

where you will able to initialize your global instances.

In the activities fetch the instance of MyApplication downcasting with:

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I gave th eother guy the answer just cuz he answered first sorry :/

Comment: What would be advantage of this if one can just create a simple separate class with static variables?

Comment: @mschonaker I do not know if you know what is wrong, but I am following this example pretty closely but am having some problems. Wherever I call (MyApplication)getApplication(), the program crashes and I receive a "ClassCastException." If you have any ideas on what I should do please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Check here : http://www.kodejava.org/examples/12.html

and here : http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

and here : http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/android-global-variables/